# pass function to input onChange and then set it in state reactjs?

Tags: html, reactjs, forms, function, onchange

I just cannot figure out how to do this.

This function works to split the string of the input ID.

```
function func() {
    // Original string
    let str = urlInput.value
    // Splitting up the string
    let array = str.split(".com/");
    let joined = array[0]+".com/embed/"+array[1];
    document.write(joined);
  console.log("function happened")
}
```

I am trying to pass it through onChange and then set it in state but the function isn't being passed onChange?

```
           {
            currentAccount ? (<textarea 
            placeholder={spotifyLink}
            type="url"
            id="urlInput"
            onChange={e => {{func}; setMessageValue(e.target.value)}}/>) : null
            }
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I pass the function and then setState after the function has split the user input string onChange?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of controlled components. With this approach, the input value is controlled by a state. It promotes single source of truth, you can read more [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components).

**CODE** -

```js
function TextAreaComponent() {
  const [messageValue, setMessageValue] = useState('');

  const splitString = (str) => {
    // Splitting up the string
    let array = str.split(".com/");
    let joined = array[0]+".com/embed/"+array[1];
    return joined;
  }

  const handleOnChange = (event) => {
    const { value } = event.target;
    const splittedString = splitString(value);
    setMessageValue(splittedString);
  }

  return (
    <textarea 
       // placeholder={spotifyLink}
       // id="urlInput"
       type="url"
       value={messageValue}
       onChange={handleOnChange}
    />
  );
}
```